# Returning rows from a csv

Tags: android, csv, inputstream

Hi I have a csv that looks like this:

```
r1c1|r1c2|r1c3
r2c1|r2c2|r2c3
```

As you can see it is delimited by the character "|"

In my application, I am trying to explode this using input stream. Here is my code:

```
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = "|";


try {
    File initialFile = new File(myfile.txt);
    InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(targetStream));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] RowData = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            String c0 = RowData[0];
            String c1 = RowData[1];
            String c2 = RowData[2];

            Toast.makeText(mainactivity.this, c2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}catch (IOException ex) {
// handle exception
 }
```

Unfortunately, this appears to return each character in the csv as a row. The toast example above returns 1 then 2.

Any ideas how to return the proper column, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` splits string around matches of the given **regular expression**, therefore use of special character (and vertical bar is one of these) requires escaping to strip its "powers".

```
String cvsSplitBy = "\\|"
```

See docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html